# How to Convert Base 10 to Base 36

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, base36

I have two columns in my Google Sheets: one column for base 10 and one column for base 36. I have filled out my Base 10 column to go from 1 to 5,000. I would like to create a function in my script that will allow me to take in the value of the Base 10 number and return a value of base 36.  (0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) I want to keep the letter lower case so that I won't confuse the number `0` with the letter `O`.

This is what I have tried so far in my script:

```
function toBase36(decNumb) {

    var base36 = parseInt(decNumb, 36);

  return parseInt(base36);
}
```

The code above produces the following result:

[image]

How can I edit my code that that I will add the lower case letters?

Comment: `.toString(36)` uses only lower case letters, so you'll be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be much simpler to use the toString() method.

Instead of `var base36 = parseInt(decNumb, 36);`

use `var base36 = decNumb.toString(36);`

Comment: Vytautas, Thank you! I also needed to change the value of return parseInt(base36) to return base 36